# List of child components not updating correctly when deleting object from state

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a dynamic form where we can have a variable amount of facilities. I want to be able to remove specific facilities as needed, but I'm having trouble with making the delete work properly. If I have three facilities and delete the second one, the page always appears like I deleted the last one, even though the state correctly reflects the deletion.

I've tried looking into how rendering and updating works, but I'm rather at a loss at how React does this entire process. It correctly renders that a deletion occurs, but it doesn't update the props of the child components correctly (I believe).

```
class Request extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      facilities: [],
      ...
    }

    this.removeFacility = this.removeFacility.bind(this);
  }

  removeFacility = (number) => (event) => {
    var newArray = [...this.state.facilities];
    var index = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
      if (newArray[i].number === number) {
        index = i;
      }
    }

    if (index !== -1) {
      newArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
      newArray[i].number = i + 1;
    }

    this.setState({facilities: newArray});
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      ...
        <div>
          {this.state.facilities.map(function(f, idx) {
              return (
                <FacilityRequest
                  key={idx}
                  facility={f}
                  removeFacility={this.removeFacility.bind(this)}/>
              )
          }, this)}
        </div>
        ...
    );
  }
}

class FacilityRequest extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { classes, key, facility, removeFacility} = this.props;
    return (
      <Paper>
        ...
        {facility.number}
        <Button onClick={removeFacility(facility.number)}>Delete</Button>
        ...
        Various form fields
        ...

      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click delete for a specific facility, the state correctly deletes the facility I want gone, but the last facility is the one that is removed (the other fields in the form remain the same as the one that was supposed to be removed, not matching the state.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because you're using the array index as a key to the components you're rendering.

The short explanation is that React uses keys to determine when to re-render mapped components.  By using index as a key, and you remove the item at index `4`, React will not see that index `4` was deleted, but that it was modified, since something else took its place.  This can have some strange side-effects, such as what you're seeing.

You're better off providing a unique identifier to key, such that it identifies the actual element and its content.  In this case, `facility.number` could be a good candidate:

```
{this.state.facilities.map(function(f, idx) {
    return (
        <FacilityRequest
            key={f.number}
            facility={f}
            removeFacility={this.removeFacility.bind(this)}/>
    )
}, this)}
```

The best key to use will depend on your implementation, of course.

[Using an index as a component key should generally be a last resort.](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: This didn't quite fix the problem, as I also changed the facility.number to match the index, but I created a new id for each facility that was unique and unchanging and used that for the key. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: You could also create `newArray` without the deleted facility with `var newArray = this.state.facilities.filter((f) => f.number !== number)`